# What API should I release my app in?

Tags: android, api, sdk, release

Should I always release at the highest level (8 at the current moment) or should I backtrack as far back as possible?  Or does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the current distribution: http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html. Obviously, you want the lowest possible API to make sure that you can reach as many users as possible. Targeting 1.6 will lose almost 8% of your potential audience. Targeting 2.0+ will lose more than 20%.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a good reference that shows what APIs were released in each release so I can check the compatibility of the imports I have made?

Comment: Each API corresponds to a version number. "1.5" is 3, "1.6" is 4, "2.0" is 5, "2.01" is 6, "2.1" is 7, "2.2" is 8. (Unless I got that wrong). If you look at the docs, every method and every constant shows when it was introduced. You can keep reducing the build target in your settings until your app stops compiling because it uses a new API feature. (Don't forget to set the minimum SDK value in the manifest accordingly.)

Comment: You mean - by changing the project build in Project -> Properties back until I hit an API that my app will not run in?

Comment: Correct. At some point, you will get build errors. That's when you know you hit a dependency.